# Using the ADT Android designer outside of Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

Is it possible to use the ADT Android layout designer outside of Eclipse? If so, what is necessary to do that?

I realize the ADT is a plug-in to Eclipse, but I am hoping that with a small amount of hacking it could be used outside of the Eclipse environment. Even just being able to edit an Android layout without it being a part of an Eclipse Android project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use droid draw to modify your layouts outside eclipse. http://droiddraw.org/